# SQL Exception thrown at prepared statement

Tags: sql, sqlite, syntax, runtime-error

Something about my prepared statement stops my program when this line is reached, and I'm not sure why, because the exact same syntax works for another table (Product, with 9 values).

FYI Order exists and has 6 columns

```
PreparedStatement statement = 
    connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Order VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

This is within a try/catch block, and obviously I set the values after this statement, but it's AT the prepared statement that the exception is thrown.

Is the syntax wrong somehow? Or does this imply that the Table doesn't exist even though the picture I attached shows it?

[image: Screenshot from Sqlite Studio]

Comment: `Order` is a SQL reserved word, so that might be part of your problem....

Answer (score 1):

`order` is a reserved word in SQL. If you want to use it as a table name, you need to escape it (by surrounding it with double quotes):

```
PreparedStatement statement = 
    connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO \"Order\" VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Comment: Whoa, woops. Thanks!